# I want to loop through an array and modify attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

**Here is my code**

```
var input_buttons = ["#one","#two","#three"]; 
var substr = input_buttons.split(',');
for(var i=0; i< substr.length; i++) 
{
   substr.attr('value', '');
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You need to tell us, what your code is it supposed to do, because that doesn't make any sense at all. `input_buttons` is an array and arrays doesn't have a method `split`. Strings do have a method `split` which returns an array and array's don't have a method `attr` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an array, there is nothing to split, this only works on strings. You'd also have to pass the ID to jQuery before you can cal `attr`. In this case `val` is even better.

```
var input_buttons = ["#one","#two","#three"]; 
for(var i=input_buttons.length; i--;) {
   $(input_buttons[i]).val('');
}
```

But shorter would be using the [*multiple selector*](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('#one, #two, #three').val('');
```

or if you already have the array, create a string by `join`ing the IDs:

```
$(input_buttons.join(',')).val('');
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first problem is calling split(',') on an array. However, if you just want to set the values of all those to a blank string you can do:

```
$('#one,#two,#three').val('');
```

If you want to set different values you'd need to loop through:

```
$('#one,#two,#three').each(function() {
  // this == the HTML node (not a jQuery element)
  this.value = someValue; // someValue would set outside
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering why you are calling:

```
var substr = input_buttons.split(',');
```

By the nature of your input_buttons, you already have an array. All you should have to do is:

```
var input_buttons = ["#one","#two","#three"]; 
for(var i=0; i< substr.length; i++) 
{
   $(input_buttons[i]).attr('value', '');
}
```

Comment: Strings don't have a methods `attr`.

Comment: @RoToRa - Doh. I always make that stupid error. Thank you for the correction. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input_buttons = ["#one","#two","#three"]; 
$.each(input_buttons, function(idx, value) {
    $(value).val('');
});
```

Or even better and shorter:

```
$('#one, #two, #three').val('');
```

You could also give those elements a common class name and then use this:

```
$('.className').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

your array contains just the id but not the actual object
try this

```
var input_buttons = ["#one","#two","#three"]; 

for(var i=0; i< input_buttons.length; i++) 
{
   $(input_buttons[i]).removeAttr('value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to remove an attribute:

```
var input_buttons = ["#one","#two","#three"]; 
for(var i=0; i< input_buttons.length; i++) 
{
   $(input_buttons[i]).removeAttr('value');
}
```

The reason your code does not work is in the overloading of jQuery functions.  `.attr('value', '')` evaluates to `.attr('value')`, which returns the value of `value` as opposed to setting it.  The reason is that `''` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Thanks, never knew about removeAttr, but my problem persits with your code. It's not the substr.removeAttr('value'); or substr.attr('value', ''); I feel but probably a syntax error?

Comment: substr is not a jquery object. needs to be initialized

Comment: `substr` is nowhere defined in your code. And of course `.attr('value', '')` should set the value of `value` to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`input_buttons` is already an array - don't `split` it.

To use `.attr` you need it to be a jquery object, so call `$(input_buttons[i]).attr`